# Unable to connect to mongodb running in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am running my application with mongodb and spriing boot, I am running my application in docker, now I want to connect mongodb running in docker to mongodb compass, for that I got the IP address of my mongob container by this command

> docker inspect -f '{{range
> .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' af931f938e28

> 172.19.0.2

and below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8" services:   api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db   mongo_db:
    image: "mongo"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: ["--bind_ip", "0.0.0.0"]
```

and I am trying to connect using below way in mongdb compass
*mongodb://172.19.0.2:27017*

but it is getting timed out, not sure why?

Comment: Since you're using Docker Compose's [default networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#title), can't you just connect to `mongodb://mongo_db:27017` (even without exposing that port under `ports:`)?

Comment: getting `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo_db`

Comment: Judging from the formatting of the compose file (there are syntax errors), it's edited from the real file. Does the original include any `network:` sections? You might have put the `api_service` and `mongo_db` containers in different virtual networks.

Comment: No it didn't have network section, is it possible for you to have a look and rectify?